# Convergence of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

We are given the sequence $\{x_n\}$. Assume that any subsequence of this sequence is convergent to $0$. Prove that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ also converges to $0$.

Here is what I did: since any subsequence converges to 0, then we have:
$\forall \epsilon > 0,\ \exists n_{0}\in \mathbb{N},\ \forall n_{k}\geq k\geq n_{0}: \ \left | x_{n_{k}} -0\right |< \epsilon  $. Then I don't know how to take it from here. Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to prove. Any sequence $(a_n)$ is a subsequence of itself. So any fact true for **all** subsequences of $(a_n)$ is automatically true of $(a_n)$.

**Remark:** The **other** direction, the one not asked about, does require proof. It is the assertion that if the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $a$, then every infinite subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to $a$.